# Unable to execute `sudo make` while installing tplink tn722n driver

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to enable monitor using tp-link tp-wn722n v2/3 connected to Raspberry Pi 4 model B 2GB. My OS details are (using Kali-ARM 32bit version although R Pi is 64bit).

PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"

NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"

ID=kali

VERSION="2022.1"

VERSION_ID="2022.1"

VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"

ID_LIKE=debian

ANSI_COLOR="1;31"

I get the following error when I run `make` command in the CLI.
[image: error pic]

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to install the drivers for your rtl8188eus and don't want to modify the source, you could also install the dkms package via apt.

`apt install realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms`